# Need help proving an equation using set theory algebra

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

The question is as follows:

> Assume $(\Omega, F, P)$ and let $A\in F$ and $B\in F$, and $A\subseteq B$. Show that $P(B \cap A') = P(B) − P (A)$.

I tried to apply the rule $P(B \cap A) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$ which gave me the result:

$P(A') + P(B) - P(A' \cup B) = P(B) - P(A)$

Then I assumed $P(A') = 1 - P(A)$ which gave me $1 - P(A) + P(B) - P(A' \cup B) = P(B) - P(A)$

This doesn't feel entirely right since I have trouble seeing how $1 - P(A' \cup B) = 0$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the math thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A' \cup B)$ should equal 1 because $A' \cup B = \Omega$. In particular, fix $\omega \in \Omega$. If $\omega \in A$, then $\omega \in B$ and thus $\omega \in A' \cup B$. Alternatively, if $\omega \notin A$ then $\omega \in A'$ and thus $\omega \in A' \cup B$.

More importantly, it looks like you're starting off by assuming what you want to show, by writing

$$ P(B) - P(A) = P(A') + P(B) - P(A' \cup B) $$

and then hoping to conclude something correct, which isn't a valid method of proof (maybe there's a contradiction out there that you happened to miss, or maybe the conclusion of the claim is possible but not guaranteed to hold).

One way to tackle this problem is to show that $P(B \cap A') + P(A) = P(B)$, which is equivalent to your original claim. Can you use the fact that $A \subseteq B$ and that probability turns disjoint unions into sums to see why this is true?

Answer (score 0):

You did not use the hypothesis that $A \subseteq B$.

Observe that $\Pr(B) = \Pr(A \cap B) + \Pr(A' \cap B)$.  Therefore, $\Pr(A' \cap B) = \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(B) - \Pr(A)$ since $A \subseteq B \implies A \cap B = A$.